# Chrome not recognising attachment filename

Tags: google-chrome, http, http-headers

We have a web application which offers a file named `L_2804071.key` for download. The download works fine in Internet Explorer and FireFox but in Chrome it "loses" the filename and chrome does not seem to recognize the filename in the content-disposition header.

Here is the full header (identical in both browsers):

```
content-disposition: attachment; =?utf-16le?B?ZmlsZW5hbWU9TF8yODA0MDcxLmtleQ==?=
```

I don't know if this helps but if you decode `=?utf-16le?B?ZmlsZW5hbWU9TF8yODA0MDcxLmtleQ==?=` you get `Wfilename=L_2804071.key` which looks weird. Not sure where the "W" comes from but IE seems to work with it and downloads a file named `L_2804071.key`.

Answer (score -1):

Fix the web application to return a Content-Disposition header field that follows the spec, your example is invalid (for starters, there's no "filename" parameter). Note that your example appears to use RFC2047-style encoding, which in general isn't used in Content-Disposition.

See http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc6266.html for details.

Comment: As your link indicates - see `4.3 Disposition Parameter: 'Filename'` - the filename parameter is completely valid. Which explains why it works in IE and FF.

Comment: Your example doesn't even have a "filename" parameter; if this "works" in IE and FF is because they have header field parsers that confuse decoding and parsing.

Comment: It seems that the reason things work in IE and FF is because the filename is also specified in the URL path after a semi-colon and Chrome is ignoring this (Chromium Issue 323156). So all browsers ignore the Wfilename nonsense.